# facing issue with day in mvc when selecting through datepicker

Tags: model-view-controller

I am facing DateTime issue in MVC, wherein when I select the date from date picker in the kendo grid in my model flightarrivalmodel i have a property called departure date. every time it will take 1 day less than selected.  ex: if I select 3-12-2019 in the model it will be 2-12-2019, can you please tell me the root cause for this the code is very simple.
I have a property with a departure date as DateTime datatype. code as follows

```
[UIHint("Date")] 
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you mean 1 month not 1 day? Months go from 0-11 in JavaScript. So you may need to add 1 somewhere in your JavaScript.

Comment: 1 day not 1 month.

Comment: It's probably a local issue then. Dates like 3-12-2019 and 2-12-2019 are often read a month-day-year. Clearly, your local understands them as day-month-year. You'll have to check the expected date format for the various components you're using and make sure to reformat the date as required. As something must be swapping day and month.